# NextJS and Redux clearing store when changing pages

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, next.js

I have been working on a project that is using NextJS and Redux. I was able to use some of the [NextJS examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples) to get redux setup with thunk, but I am having issues with the redux state persisting across pages.

So I know that you can use NextJS with Redux, but whenever I use `href` it will clear my redux store.

How do I get Redux to persist across different pages?

Comment: Hey man. How did you solve this? My redux store is being cleared whenever there is a page change.

Comment: @s.khan see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the advantages to NextJS was that there is a built in React Router hook called `useRouter`, but what I didn't realize is that if you are going to use Redux you have to use `useRouter` because otherwise it will trigger another Server Side Render and will reset your state back to the initialState that you set up.

Another fly in the ointment is that when you use NextJS it is difficult to access the localStorage if you are wanting to store user information in there without bringing in another piece of react. To do this you need to run a `localStorage` call when the page is loaded (So either using `useEffect` or in `componentDidMount`)

I will eventually do a write-up on this after I finish setting up my initial project. Hopes this helps someone.